# go + gorgonia + cuda + Docker: Error in initialization - see "group__CUDA__INITIALIZE.html" for details on: NoDevice

Tags: docker, go, cuda

I am trying to get go running with CUDA support in a Docker container.

My setup on the host system is as follows:

- Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS (*from* `cat /etc/os-release`)
- GPU: TU106 [GeForce RTX 2070] (*from* `lshw -C display`)
- CUDA: (*from* `nvidia-smi`)

  - NVIDIA-SMI 515.65.01
  - Driver Version: 515.65.01
  - CUDA Version: 11.7
- cudnn: (*from* `cat /usr/local/cuda/include/cudnn_version.h | grep CUDNN_MAJOR -A 2`)

  - CUDNN_MAJOR: 8
  - CUDNN_MINOR: 7

My Docker Image Details

- Base Image: nvidia/cuda:10.2-cudnn7-devel-centos7
- go: verion 1.20
- gorgonia: version 0.9.15
- gorgonia/cu: version 0.9.3

My project structure is as follows:

- `Dockerfile`
- `main.go`
- `go.mod`

Here is my `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM nvidia/cuda:10.2-cudnn7-devel-centos7

USER root
EXPOSE 8080
ENV GOVERSION=1.20

RUN yum upgrade -y --nogpgcheck \
    && yum install -y --nogpgcheck curl git
RUN curl -O https://dl.google.com/go/go${GOVERSION}.linux-amd64.tar.gz

# env for go and gpu
RUN tar -C /usr/local -xzf go${GOVERSION}.linux-amd64.tar.gz
ENV CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES="0"
ENV CUDA_PATH=/usr/local/cuda
ENV PATH="$PATH::/usr/local/go/bin"
ENV LD_LIBRARY_PATH="$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/local/cuda-10.2/compat"

# cudatest
RUN mkdir -p /opt/go/cudatest
WORKDIR /opt/go/cudatest
COPY cudatest/go.mod /opt/go/cudatest/
COPY cudatest/main.go /opt/go/cudatest/
RUN go get gorgonia.org/cu@v0.9.3
RUN go mod tidy
RUN go build -tags="cuda"

CMD ["go", "run", "."]
```

And here is the `main.go` which is simply `~/go/pkg/mod/gorgonia.org/cu@v0.9.3/cmd/cudatest/main.go`.

```
// cudatest tests the existence of CUDA by running a simple Go program that uses CUDA.
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "os"

    "gorgonia.org/cu"
    "github.com/cloudflare/cfssl/log"
)

func main() {
    fmt.Printf("\nCUDA version: %v\n", cu.Version())
    devices, err := cu.NumDevices()
    if err != nil {
        log.Info("issue found: %+v", err)
        os.Exit(1)
    }
    fmt.Printf("CUDA devices: %v\n\n", devices)

    for d := 0; d < devices; d++ {
        name, _ := cu.Device(d).Name()
        cr, _ := cu.Device(d).Attribute(cu.ClockRate)
        mem, _ := cu.Device(d).TotalMem()
        maj, _ := cu.Device(d).Attribute(cu.ComputeCapabilityMajor)
        min, _ := cu.Device(d).Attribute(cu.ComputeCapabilityMinor)
        fmt.Printf("Device %d\n========\nName      :\t%q\n", d, name)
        fmt.Printf("Clock Rate:\t%v kHz\n", cr)
        fmt.Printf("Memory    :\t%v bytes\n", mem)
        fmt.Printf("Compute   : \t%d.%d\n\n", maj, min)
    }
}
```

Even though unnecessary I use my own `go.mod`

```
module cudatest
        go 1.20
        require gorgonia.org/cu v0.9.3
        require github.com/pkg/errors v0.8.1 // indirect
```

To build the image:

```
docker build -t goinvidia -f Dockerfile .
```

Running the container with

```
docker run -it --rm --gpus all  goinvidia
```

results into the error message

```
Error in initialization, please refer to "https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-driver-api/group__CUDA__INITIALIZE.html" for details on: NoDevice
exit status 1
```

Running

```
docker run -it --rm --gpus all  goinvidia nvidia-smi
```

shows correctly existance of the GPU (*I guess*):

```
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 515.65.01    Driver Version: 515.65.01    CUDA Version: 10.2     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|                               |                      |               MIG M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  NVIDIA GeForce ...  On   | 00000000:01:00.0 Off |                  N/A |
|  0%   37C    P8     2W / 175W |     64MiB /  8192MiB |      0%      Default |
|                               |                      |                  N/A |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
                                                                               
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                                  |
|  GPU   GI   CI        PID   Type   Process name                  GPU Memory |
|        ID   ID                                                   Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

So, is it a `go` problem?